# MySQL connection on a non-standard port

Tags: config, mysql

We were experimenting with running an EE database stored on AWS and we found that MySQL was running on a non-standard port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thought was we'd add a config var for the MySQL port as per the CodeIngiter docs

```
$db['default']['port'] = 5432
```

but that didn't work instead we had to change the hostname to

```
$db['expressionengine']['hostname'] = "mysqldbinstance.hostname.com:4703";
```